# Robotium - "Controlling built in app"

Tags: android, robotium

**Hi i am using Robotium tool for automation, i have a developed a sample app to send mail and it uses Built in app ie: gmail to send it, i am not able to click or do any operations on the gmail pop up... **  Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Robotium can only control the application it instruments. This means it is not possible to automate one of the built in applications as well as your own application. (You can strip the signing on a built in application and resign it and automate that, but then you would not be able to automate your own application!).

Where does this leave me then? i hear you say!

1. Well, you you can test around the problem by making sure your application sends the right intent to the mail app using robotium. (hint, intent filters)
2. If you can accept testing on 4.1+ then use http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html
3. If you can accept using only emulators, look into automation via hierarchy viewer/monkey